# How to add UIButtons and UILabels to a Scrollable View?

Tags: ipad, uiview, xcode4, uibutton, scroll

I've seen almost every question about similar issues, and tried the given answers, but they are not working for me. The thing is: I have a home view, and I have a button, on click, it adds a new button and a label over it, and so on until you "fill" the area, and I want it to be resizable and scrollable, so you can see all the buttons and you can zoom-in to see just some buttons. I don't know if I'm explaining myself clearly...

So, I tried adding everything to a UIView, and it didn't work, I tried adding everything to a UIScrollView, and again it didn't work. I don't know what else to do. I've been dealing with this almost all week without any success. I have to say I am not very experienced on this, I just started to code for iOS about 4 months ago, so please be patient. I would really appreciate any help or guidance you can share.

Here's what I am doing:

```
- (IBAction) doneAdding:(id) sender{
        boxes = boxes+1;
        UIButton *newBox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        UIImage *boxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bluecube.jpg"];

    if (boxes <= 4) {
    switch (boxes) {
        case 1:
            newBox.frame = CGRectMake(519, 356, 162, 163);
            break;
        case 2:
            newBox.frame = CGRectMake(681, 519, 162, 163);
            break;
        case 3:
            newBox.frame = CGRectMake(357, 519, 162, 163);
            break;
        case 4:
            newBox.frame = CGRectMake(519, 844, 162, 163);
            break;
            default:
            break;
    }

    [newBox setBackgroundImage:boxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [newBox addTarget:self action:@selector(goToProject:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [homeView addSubview:newBox];


            //I get the text of the label from a textfield 
    UILabel *nameLabel= [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(480.0,500.0, 150.0, 43.0) ];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: newName.text forKey: @"SomeRandomText"];
    nameLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:(12.0)];
    nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", newName.text];
    [homeView addSubview:nameLabel];
    [newName release];


     }else {
        NSLog(@"No more boxes allowed");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Did you try setting the `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` property to a size large enough to contain all the subview's frames?

Comment: yes I did, but it just won't scroll. I checked all the checkboxes that have to be checked on the IB, but no luck.

Comment: I don't see any `[homeView setContentSize:]` there.

Comment: I didn't set it programmatically, I stated that inside the IB... is there any difference?

Comment: You have to adjust it every time you add a new button, and it of course has to be larger than the bounds size of the scroll view...

Comment: oh... silly me. So there HAS to be a scroll view? or could it just be the view?